# onMouseLeave not working correct in React next to same class

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on creating a navbar, with dropdowns opening on hover. This is what I'm doing:

```
menu.push(
 <SplitButton
  className="nav-item has-dropdown"
  title={menuArray[item].title}
  href={menuArray[item].link.uri_alias ? menuArray[item].link.uri_alias : menuArray[item].link.uri.replace("internal:", "")}
  onMouseEnter={() => setHoverState({...hoverState, [item]: true})}
  onMouseLeave={() => setHoverState({...hoverState, [item]: false})}
  show={hoverState[item]}
 >
   {buildDropdown(menuArray[item].children)}
 </SplitButton>
)
```

Everything is working fine, except when I trigger "onMouseLeave" going to adjacent SplitButton component, it doesn't get triggered correctly. Triggering it by completely moving out of navbar or a nav item without dropdown which has completely different class and structure works fine. Could you help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are having problems with the asynchronous set of state. As you "inmediately" `mouseLeave` one `SplitButton` and `mouseEnter` into another `SplitButton`, both are executing `setHoverState`, hence "collapsing" due to different references of `hoverState`.

So, first you should change the `setHoverState` to use:

`setHoverState(prevState => ({...prevState, [item]: true/false})`

It should work that way. After that, I would recommend a much easier way to manage this kind of ON/OFF situations. You can have a state with all the `hoveredItems` that is initialized with `[]`. So, whenever `mouseEnter` the button, that item is appended to the array, and whenever `mouseLeave` the button, the items is filtered out of the array.

To check if an element is hovered you can just check if the `hoveredItems` state `includes(item)`

Comment: Hey Agustin, thank you so much for an awesome explanation. The solution you suggested worked out great! I'll look into simplifying my methods of doing this :)